# Kotlin 'Unresolved reference: parcelize' error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm working on a multi-module Android application built in Kotlin and am trying to use the parcelize plugin to pass data between screens. However in my data class definition I'm getting 'unresolved reference' compiler errors against the @Parcelize annotation and Parcelable class.

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class SearchFilter(
    val id: Int?,
    val name: String?
): Parcelable
```

This is the plugins section of my project `build.gradle` file...

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version '7.4.2' apply false
    id "com.android.library" version '7.4.2' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.7.10" apply false
    id "com.google.dagger.hilt.android" version "2.42" apply false
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin" version "2.5.2" apply false
}
```

Then in my feature module's `build.gradle` file I've added this...

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.library"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
}
```

I'm using v1.8.0 of the Kotlin plugin. A couple of other similar questions mentioned about  adding the specific parcelize plugin to the project `build.gradle` file (`id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize" version "1.8.20"`) however that also doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to get the plugin setup correctly?